# How to set a counter for AsyncTask?

Tags: android, counter

I have an AsyncTask that retrieves information from the internet. But when signal or wifi connection is weak. The AsyncTask times out and the app force closes.

I was thinking maybe i could have a timer set up so when the AsyncTask takes more than 20 seconds, then it Displays a dialog or even a toast, and sends the user to the previous activitiy in the class.

How would i go about doing this?

I know the smart way would be to count increasing a int

Maybe something like..

```
private class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

protected void DoInBackground(){


for(int i = 0;i<20;i++){


//DO something
```

Am i on the right track?
Some guidence would be helpful!

Comment: Why not just catch the exception that is causing the FC?  Also the AsyncTask API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html contains a few references to a timeout value. I'm not sure how exactly you are using the AsyncTask but it should be possible to use a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do something like this

```
private class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

protected void DoInBackground(){
   try{
   //do your stuff here
   }catch(Exception e){
   //something is wrong , async task may crash , show a dialog or error
}

}
```